# image upload using http multipart. if image is null then getting error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

on tap submit subbmit method call .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glYah.png

error :
successful
E/flutter (11575): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'readAsBytesSync' was called on null.
E/flutter (11575): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11575): Tried calling: readAsBytesSync()
E/flutter (11575): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (11575): #1      _Delivery_DetailsState.submitForm (package:shop_me/src/screens/product_delivery/ui/delivery_detail.dart:500:37)
E/flutter (11575): #2      _Delivery_DetailsState.build. (package:shop_me/src/screens/product_delivery/ui/delivery_detail.dart:384:33)
E/flutter (11575): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter (11575): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (11575): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
E/flutter (11575): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter (11575): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
E/flutter (11575): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (11575): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
E/flutter (11575): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
E/flutter (11575): #11     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
E/flutter (11575): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter (11575): #13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter (11575): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter (11575): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter (11575): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter (11575): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (11575): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (11575): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
E/flutter (11575): #20     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
E/flutter (11575): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
E/flutter (11575):

Comment: Sorry, but why don't you pre-check null for the image before uploading?

Comment: on submit button i am checking  _image.path.null?'':''

Comment: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'readAsBytesSync' was called on null.

Comment: following the log showed, you are trying to call `readAsBytesSync()` with a null object.

Comment: It would be better if you show where are you declaring ```_image``` and where are you assigning it.